# Can an .accdb be used as a back end to a server deployed SSRS?

Tags: ms-access, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

For my company there is a report that ends up in an access database format (.accdb) when it gets to my department.  We want to deploy an SSRS with this information.  While I was able to do it in Visual Studio the database manager questioned whether this can actually be deployed and work in the server environment. Can this this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about an Access report, or data inside of Access?

SQL server reports are not built in Access and have absolute nothing to do with Access. The only issue would be then since the report cannot be built in Access, then why attempt to have SQL server open an accDB file for the data source? You would be much better off to simply have Access transfer the table data to SQL server and then continue to use the reports built in SQL server.

So a report in Access has ZERO relationship to SQL server reports. As such, the reports in Access are of no use and if your plan is to use SSRS, then the reports have to be built in SSRS.

It is possible to place an Access accDB data file on the server and have SQL server connect such data, but it generally does not allow or work well with multiple users.

Keep in mind, the reverse is certainly possible and often recommended. You place and keep all data on SQL server tables. You then link the Access application to SQL server. In this setup then the data ALWAYS resides on SQL server, but the reports are in Access. And the general forms etc. built in Access will save + send their data to SQL server (and this works without having to write code).

The above thus suggests that the Access application with the reports has to be distributed to users that need such reports. And such users will thus all share only ONE copy of the data since such data resides on SQL server. And this setup would also allow one to create reports in SSRS without having to upload any kind of data, since the live operating data from the Access application always resides on SQL server.

So in summary:
Access reports are Access reports, just like FoxPro reports are FoxPro reports, and FileMaker reports are FileMaker reports. As such, these reports cannot be used, viewed, or utilized by SQL server in anyway.

However, the reverse is not only possible, but is a common solution. Thus the Access (front end) is linked to SQL server and the data tables for forms, code, reports etc. for the Access application now resides on SQL server.

If you place the actual accDB data file from Access ON the SQL server, then SQL server can read the data, but any code, forms, reports etc. from Access cannot be used by SQL server. So a report in Access is of ZERO use to SSRS.

So if SSRS is a goal, then anything built in Access from a user interface point of view cannot be used. SSRS thus can only consume the data in tables.

Since SSRS can ONLY consume data from Access (and nothing else), then a far better solution in place of moving up a accDB file to the server is to simply push up the data from Access tables to a SQL server tables. And if such a data transfer is to occur often, then likely better is to ALWAYS keep the tables and data in SQL server, and have the Access front end part “link” to the data on SQL server. Access reports, forms and even VBA code will in most cases run as before, but the live data always resides in SQL server. You thus eliminate all the dance and song of attempting to transfer data between two systems. The SQL server data is thus always “live” and update to date, and only ONE copy of the table data EVER exists.

Most Access applications and reports and forms can work with very few (if any) modifications when you place the data tables on SQL server, and have the front end Access part “link” to SQL server.

Since a given specialized report in SSRS is going to require a pre-determined and non changing table structure, then the most prudent solution would be to have Access link to and use the data from SQL server tables (not the other way around).

So Access reports can ONLY be used by those with Access (or the free runtime) installed on each client desktop computer. Such Access reports have to be 100% re-built if your goal is to have such reports be used with SSRS.

Comment: Data inside access. I was trying to avoid pushing the data to a table in a SQL server because of the permissions hassle that comes with such a move in a large company.  I think though Ill just bite the bullet and do it the way you recommended though, especially if there are troubles with multiple access.